# React native / Redux / Pagination - How to prevent the view to jump back to top when loading more items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, pagination

I am using react native + redux and try to implement a load more functionality. I request in my componentDidMount the first 100 items, then on click, I want to request + show the next 100 items (plus the 'old 100 items etc) --all in the same view.

Problem: My code works, only thing I cannot figure out is when I press load more button, my view jumps back to the top, while I want the view to stay at the position of the first new item loaded. Nothing I saw online really helped..Any ideas? Also I pretty new to react native and redux and would be happy about any tipps on how I could implement the (sort of) pagination better than as I am doing now.

Thanks a lot!

Container Component:

```
class App extends React.Component {    
    state = {
        counter: 1
    }    
    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.fetchData(0)
    }    
    renderItems() {
        return this.props.data.map(item =>
            <Item
                key={item.id}
                name={item.name}
                symbol={item.symbol}
            />
        )    
    }    
    loadMoreData = () => {
        if (this.state.counter>0) {
            this.props.fetchCoinData(`${this.state.counter}01`);
            this.state.counter++;
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.isFetching) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Spinner
                        visible={this.props.isFetching}
                        textContent={"Loading..."}
                    />
                </View>
            )
        }
        return (
            <View>
                <ScrollView>
                    {this.renderItems()}
                    <View>
                        <Button
                            title="Load more"
                            onPress={this.loadMoreData}
                        />
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }   
}

mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isFetching: state.dataReducer.isFetching,
        data: state.dataReducer.data
    }
}    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchData})(App)
```

In my action I dispatch (I can add the rest of the code, in case its needed):
Im always getting 100 items back from my api request (each request is limited to 100 anyways)

```
export const fetchData = (start) => {
  ...

  return axios.get(`${api_root_url}/v1/?start=${start}`)
   ....
}
```

In my reducer I attach new data from new api request to 'old' data.
my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    isFetching: null,
    data: []
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCHING__DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true
            }

        case FETCH__DATA_SUCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                data: [...state.data, ...action.payload]
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I discovered FlatList from react native and used that - however still the problem of jumping to top after fetching new data is still there..

UPDATE: Using FlatList DID solve my problem! Also, I figured out why my view kept jumping to the top - it was because in my render, I have the conditional if this.props.isFetching --> show spinner and that was causing the jump.

Comment: good job buddy... for sharing the code

Comment: hey @javascript2016, just as an fyi it's perfectly acceptable to post a solution to your own question. Glad you were able to solve it!